# Trying Favorite tab inside a .map on react. I cannot change the boolean type on mysql table

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios, sequelize.js

I have a problem with my fav' tab button. i cannot send the .post and i dont know how to solve it... Here is my frontend code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

function CompoNuevos() {
  const { state = { success: false } } = useLocation();
  const [cnuevos, setCnuevos] = useState([]);

(...)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/cnu")
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((y) => y.data)
      .then((allCnuevos) => setCnuevos(allCnuevos));
  }, []);
async function handleClick() {
  await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/oportunidades', {
    id: cnuevos.id,
    ofertas: true,
  });
}
  return (
(...)
{cnuevos &&
        cnuevos.map((cnuevo) => {
          return (
(...)
<button onClick={handleClick}>Marcar como oferta</button>
);
        })}
export default CompoNuevos;
```

and here my route:

```
import express from "express";
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../models/loadSequalize.js";
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";

const Oferta = sequelize.define(
  "Oferta",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nombre: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    precio: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    descripcion: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    data: {
      type: Sequelize.BLOB("long"),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    ofertas: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  },
  { tableName: "cnuis", timestamps: false }
);

const oportunidadesRouter = express.Router();

oportunidadesRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { id, ofertas } = req.body;

  await Oferta.update(
    { ofertas: ofertas },
    {
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    }
  );

  res.send({ success: true });
});

export default oportunidadesRouter;
```

i also have the sequelize connection and this:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
(...)
import oportunidadesRouter from './routes/oportunidades.js';
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

(...)
app.use('/api/oportunidades', oportunidadesRouter);
const port = 3001
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

anyone knows what's happening on my error?

i tryed different methods but i cannot change the boolean on the database...

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "POST http://localhost:3001/api/oportunidades net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"  I guess i cannot send the parameters to de back so api cannot be done

Comment: Probably cors error?

Comment: it says axios error

Comment: Are you sure that the server is running?

Comment: its compiling always till' i click the button and it stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `cnuevos` is an array, `cnuevos.id` will return `undefined` (and the backend logic will fail). You need to pass the `id` of the item inside the `.map` as an argument to the function `handleClick` and use this `id` on the backend endpoint